# nginx hotlinking prevention

Tags: nginx, video, hotlinking

I know this is quite a basic question, but whereas i had no problem preventing image files from hotlinking, i can't figure out how i can't protect mp4 video files…

i just tried to specify mp4 next to jpg, (that's the two filetypes i need to protect), but as it works for jpg, mp4 does nothing !

Any idea ?

```
location ~* \.(jpg|mp4)$ {
valid_referers none blocked www.mysite.com mysite.com;
if ($invalid_referer) { return 403; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately whatever method you use to "protect" the progressive
download, it can still be thwarted.

This problem is, that videos are specified as **streaming contents**.

Actually, many video-downloader tools are so powerful, so it is very
difficult to protect the video files from being downloaded.

Usually, there is a three step solution:

1. **GET** `/path/to/file` - return an HTML form with a capcha or some other method to avoid
   automa
2. **POST** `/path/to/file` - return an HTTP redirect using a secure hash
3. **GET** `/path/to/file?hash=xxx` - check the hash

You can perfect this method by implementing the [H264 Streaming Module for nginx](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Nginx-Version2).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, i'll have a look at the streaming module. Anyway, i don't realy want to protect the videos from downloading, i just don't want another website to embed the video on its own pages. Another solution anyway, could be to program a system with dynamically generated URLs so that it's not possible to copy it for further usage…